# Does Google Chrome Frame break IE8 console output?

Tags: html, debugging, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas, google-chrome-frame

This is a question about **debugging a project**, not about writing the code.

I am on the final stages of developing an `HTML5` web app. Fairly last minute, our client tells us it should run on `IE8`. Since I use the `HTML5-canvas` in the app, this required the addition of *Google Chrome Frame*. Once installed and testing, however, IE8's developer console no longer prints any data, and the HTML viewer never loads. Is this a bug? Is there a way to fix it? It will really suck if I need to debug with alerts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Google Chrome Frame documentation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started):

> You can use the Web Inspector in GCF just as you would in the Google Chrome browser. To use it, right-click and choose "Inspect Element". Logging is available via the console.log method, and you can set breakpoints and inspect network activity.

Comment: Thank you! This will save a lot of headaches. I just selected "inspect element", and sure enough - exactly what I needed!